# Kafka createDirectStream using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My main aim is to connect Kafka, create a DStream, save that to the local variable as row and write that into mongo db, and to have the End to End flow in PySpark.

But I am facing issue in the very first step, while creating DStream and the error is "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String". Can you please help me to identify the fix?
details are below,

I am trying to connect kafka using pyspark as below,

```
kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": ['host1:port','host2:port','host3:port'],
"security.protocol":"ssl",
"ssl.key.password":"***",
"ssl.keystore.location":"/path1/file.jks",
"ssl.keystore.password":"***",
"ssl.truststore.location":"/path1/file2.jks",
"ssl.truststore.password":"***"}

directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,["lac.mx.digitalchannel.raw.s015-txn-qrdc"],kafkaParams)
```

but I am getting error, Not sure how to handle it,

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o120.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$SimpleConsumerConfig$.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:419)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.config(KafkaCluster.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:721)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(KafkaUtils.scala:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, to open PySpark CLI i am using,

```
pyspark2 --master local --jars /path/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.cloudera2.jar,/path/kafka-clients-2.0.0-cdh6.1.0.jar,/path/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.cloudera2.jar  --files file.jks,file2.jks
```

Comment: Note: As of Spark 2.4, Spark Streaming API is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`metadata.broker.list` needs to be a comma separated string, not a list

> main aim is to connect Kafka, create a DStream, save that to the local variable as row and write that into mongo

1. Mongo supports Structured Streaming writes
2. Mongo also has a Kafka Connect plugin that requires just a config file, no Spark cluster or code

Comment: Thanks its working with your recommanded  changes, I have achived this with read Structured Streaming. Now stuck with Mongo. while performing write getting error as u"'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;". Do you have any advise on it?

Comment: Replace with `writeStream`